# Rigorously deriving the expression for polarization current

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, polarization, dielectric

Is there a way to properly show that the polarization current associated with a polarization $\vec P$ is $\frac{\partial\vec P}{\partial t}$?

I've seen a lot of heuristic arguments and would appreciate a rigorous derivation of the same,also there is this answer on SE that addresses a similar question https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/467985/304878
but doesn't explain how $\nabla\cdot(\vec J_p-\frac{\partial\vec P}{\partial t})=0$ implies $\vec J_p=\frac{\partial\vec P}{\partial t}$

Edit:This is my first exposure to classical electrodynamics and the above implied statement is not at all obvious to me,as far as I know to determine a vector field uniquely we need to know it's divergence,curl and it's value on the pertinent boundaries, I don't seem to get how divergence alone would determine the field uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove it, because it's a definition.

Recall the following definitions:
\begin{align}
D &= \epsilon_0 E + P \\
H &= \frac{B}{\mu_0} - M \\
\rho_b &= -\nabla \cdot P \\
J_b &= \nabla \times M
\end{align}

Our objective is to make the macroscopic version of Ampère–Maxwell law look like this:
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times H = J_f + \frac{\partial D}{\partial t}
\end{equation}

Now
\begin{align}
\nabla \times H
&= \nabla \times (B/\mu_0 - M) \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu_0} \nabla \times B - \nabla \times M \\
&= \frac{1}{\mu_0}(\mu_0 J + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}) - J_b \\
&= J - J_b + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
J_f + \frac{\partial D}{\partial t} = J_f + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial t}
\end{align}

so in order for these quantities to be equal, it must be the case that

\begin{equation}
J - J_b = J_f + \frac{\partial P}{\partial t}
\end{equation}

in other words, the total current $J$ is made up of three contributions: the bound current $J_b$ (whose definition was given above), $J_f$, and a third quantity $\partial P/\partial t$. So if we call $J_f$ the free current, then it means $\partial P/\partial t$ is neither bound nor free, and the name "polarization current" is given to it.

Comment: So $\vec J_p$=$\frac{\partial\vec P}{\partial t}$ is to be taken as an axiom/experimental input if we choose to take only one of the above two versions of maxwells equations as an axiom to the theory?

Comment: @Arjun There are no axioms in physics. It's true by *definition*. A statement that is true by definition doesn't actually express any truth about the physical world. It's just a convention about what name we give to a particular quantity.

Answer (score 0):

The polarization bound current comes from the time derivative of the electric dipole moment of a molecule
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\bf p}{dt}=\sum_i q_i\frac{d{\bf r}_i}{dt},
\end{equation}
where the sum is over all the charges in the molecule.
When this is related to the polarization $\bf P$, which is the dipole moment per unit volume, it corresponds to the bound current $\partial_t{\bf P}$.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this a definition? $\mathbf{J}_\mathrm{P}\equiv\partial_\mathrm{t}\mathbf{P}$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you are clarifying, please do so in comments. ( negative voting for the same)

Comment: It looks like that commenting needs "reputation" on SE, which I unfortunately do not have.